# How to limit the input in an entry field?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Writing a UI which eventually modifies a text file, I wanted to know if I could make sure that the input by the user is within the predefined range.

For example I want the user to enter only values ranging from 10000 to 99999

```
label .labelSalary -text "Enter Salary"
entry .entrySalary -width 20 -relief sunken -textvariable salary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `-validate`, `-validatecommand` and `-invalidcommand` options for the [`entry` widget](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/entry.htm): a demo

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require Tk

proc validateSalary {} {
    expr {$::salary eq "" || (10000 <= $::salary && $::salary <= 99999)}
}

proc invalidSalary {} {
    tk_messageBox -type ok -icon warning \
        -title "Invalid Salary" \
        -message "Salary $::salary is not in the requested range" 
}

label .labelSalary -text "Enter Salary"
entry .entrySalary -width 20 -relief sunken -textvariable salary \
    -validate focusout \
    -validatecommand validateSalary \
    -invalidcommand invalidSalary

pack .labelSalary .entrySalary -side left
```

Comment: Can I limit the value inside as a part of the entry command?for example I learned that I can limit the value to be 8 integers by "entry .entrySalary -width 20 -relief sunken -textvariable salary -validate key -validatecommand {expr [string length %P] <= 8}"

Comment: So can I do something along with range in the same entry command?

Comment: The validate command can be anything that returns a boolean value. You can make it as complex as you require. As you've shown, it doesn't even need to be a separate `proc`, however using a proc does improve reusability and readability.

Comment: oh ok, BTW I tried the method you mentioned in the answer but everytime I try to enter a value in the field it errors out saying " Error: bad option " ":must be -default,-icon,-message,-parent,-title or -type"

Comment: make sure the line continuation backslash is **not** followed by **any whitespace**. It must be the last character on the line.

Comment: ahh sorry my bad

Comment: In hindsight, change `$::salary eq ""` in the validate code to `string is integer $::salary`

Comment: Writing a good rejecting validation routine isn't always very easy as it needs to handle transient invalid states as well. On-submit validation is much easier to get right.

Comment: Donal, can you elaborate with the current example in mind?